# How to redirect users to page without changing the URL directory?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have this navigation bar code:

```
$('#navContent a').on('click', function(event) {
        
        var page = $(this).attr('href'); // Get link name

        $('body').load('pages/' + page + '.php'); // Load clicked page
               
        
        window.history.pushState('state', 'title', page); // Change URL

        return false;

});
```

When the user clicks the element `#navContent a` it adds the href attribute [of the anchor] to a URL that it `.load()`s [the URL] into the `body`, then it adds the same `href` attribute to the address bar of the page without redirecting the page (`return false`).

An example of that URL on click would be:

> [www.example.com/Inventory](http://www.example.com/Inventory)

If the user decides to refresh the above URL it will bring them to a error 404 page as that page doesn't exist.

---

I want the user to be able to enter/refresh that URL and have it redirect to the page with the code above with a trigger linking to the `page` requested on load. How can I go about doing that?

Comment: Two choices. 1) Use url hash instead of virtual path or 2) use mod rewrite in htaccess to account for the virtual directories. Using hash is simplest

Comment: I was thinking about going with option 2 but when I 
`RewriteRule ^/inventory.* / [P]` (I turned `
RewriteEngine On` earlier in the document) it redirects as expected but removes the directory. (From www.example.com/inventory to www.example.com/) how do I change the rewrite rule to redirect without changing the directory?

Comment: Make sure you are changing the url with valid one, if it is not it will give 404

Comment: you are loading html content from ```'pages/' + page + '.php'``` and changing url to ```page ``` only.

Comment: change ```window.history.pushState('state', 'title', page);``` to ```window.history.pushState('state', 'title', 'pages/' + page + '.php');``` it will work

Comment: @MuhammadSaquibShaikh I am not changing the URL to a valid one on purpose. I want the page to redirect to the index page but keeping the directory on load

Comment: change the url with that page url which should be loaded when refreshed. If that url is not valid it will give 404

Comment: @MuhammadSaquibShaikh I was gonna try that next but noticed if I change the .htaccess rewrite rules I can redirect successfully but it will change the URL to the redirected page. So when entering www.example.com/inventory it redirects to www.example.com, instead I want to keep www.example.com/inventory in the address bar.